# Save an animation at the final step as a figure

Tags: python-2.7, animation, matplotlib

I wrote a script which animates the results I obtained, using matplotlib.

Besides the animation I got, I wanted to save the figure at the final step of the animation; just before the animation is repeated. I defined a save-flag, to avoid the figure being saved over and over. You can see the simplified version of my code below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

x = np.array(range(12))
y = np.array([i**2 for i in range(12)])

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim = (0,15), ylim = (0,150))
line, = ax.plot([],[], 'o-')

def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return line,

save_flag = False
def animate(i):
    i = (i+1)%(len(x)+1)
    line.set_data(x[0:i], y[0:i])

    global save_flag   
    if (save_flag == False) and (i == (len(x)-1)):
        print "\nThe figure is being saved!\n"
        fig.savefig("foo" + ".png")
        save_flag = True

    return line,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, repeat=True, blit=True, init_func=init)
plt.show()
```

If you run the script, you will probably see that, at the end of the first loop, the the animation becomes erroneous. This error is due to the `blit`, which is set `True`. However, if it is set to `False`, then the figure repeats itself as it should be.

Why is there such a problem; could it be a bug? (My Python version is 2.7.5+.)

Is there a better way to save a figure at the end of an animation?

Comment: I actually can't reproduce your problem on my machine. However, the display problems when blitting could be a side-effect of `savefig` changing the figure's DPI when it's called.  What happens if you do `fig.savefig('foo.png', dpi=fig.dpi)` instead?